# CanCan: wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I can't seem to get CanCan working. This has turned out to be quite frustrating, especially when I have followed the rule book and tried, seemingly, all the tricks under the sun to get it to work.

I am using Rails 3.1.2, Devise 2.1.2, and CanCan 1.6.8. I set-up a separate role model as described by RyanB [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Separate-Role-Model).

This is my code.

**1) ability.rb**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initializer(user)
    user ||= User.new  # For users with no account

    if (user.has_role?(:admin)) || (user.has_role?(:mod))
      can :manage, :all

    elsif user.has_role?(:registered)
      can :read, :all
      can :create, :all

      can :update, Question do |question|
        question.try(:user) == (user || user.has_role?(:admin) || user.has_role?(:mod))
      end

      can :destroy, Question do |question|
        question.try(:user) == (user || user.has_role?(:admin) || user.has_role?(:mod))
      end

    else
      can :read, :all        
    end
  end
end
```

**2) has_role? definition in user.rb**

```
def has_role?(role_sym)
  roles.any? { |r| r.name.underscore.to_sym == role_sym }
end
```

**3) Controller before filters**

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => :show

load_and_authorize_resource
skip_authorize_resource :only => :show
```

Authorizing any controller with CanCan results in the same error on all actions.

**EDIT: Stack Trace**

```
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb:352:in `initialize'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb:352:in `new'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb:352:in `current_ability'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:207:in `current_ability'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:77:in `load_collection?'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:33:in `load_resource'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `block in add_before_filter'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run__458654864__process_action__156152648__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:589:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__446710069__call__461654473__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/home/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1

.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: You should add the line number on which the error occurs, and the line of code in question.

Comment: Well for index pages, it does not specifies where the error is. In the show page it does, on `if can? :update, @question`. But as is obvious, the problem is not there in the view, it's in the ability class itself.

Comment: Can you update and add the stack trace with the error?

Comment: Which controller are those filters in?

Comment: Updated with stack trace, sorry for not including it in the first place.

Comment: @KyleC Any controller I put the authorization on, either on individual actions or with `load_and_authorize_resource`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it seems, I did not followed ALL the rules of the rule book. Although I cannot see how this could be a problem. To get this working, I deleted my ***ability.rb*** file that I created manually, and used the `rails g cancan:ability` command to generate the same file in the same directory, and used the same code. And now it works like a charm.

Comment: This probably saved me a lot of time.  Thanks!

At the same time this also stinks because my original ability.rb file was identical to the one I ended up creating with the generator, and the generator only seemed to make that file and nothing else so there's no way to figure out what else could have been changed.  Strange.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this in a weird way, but I found that, in our case, we did not define the `initialize` method. I did as you found worked to see what the generator created, which added an empty (filled with notes) `initialize(user)` method. My tests ran as expected after getting the ArgumentError from `can?` calls.

Looking at your original code, it looks like your def name is `initializer`
For me, it's always `initalize` vs `initialize`... gets me every time. ;)